# JQueryUI: getting accordion id by its index

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how can I get an id of accordion header knowing its index?

```
$( ".accordion:visible" ).accordion( "option", "active", accordionIndex );
```

Can I somehow perform click on the accordion using syntax above or similar?
(I read api documentation, I know there is no click event in option, I just need to click on it when I have no id and I wonder if there is any way of doing that)

Thanks in advance,
Sliwczy

edit:
ggzone helped me to figure out the solution:

```
var header = $('.accordion > h3').get(accordionIndex); 
alert(header.id);
```

Comment: var headerID = $('.accordion > h3').index(accordionIndex).attr('id');

Comment: @ggzone code you suggested didn't worked for me, but thank you anyway because using your example I figured out how to do that:

var header = $('.accordion > h3').get(accordionIndex);
alert(header.id);